# Jquery - Highlight all divs with same class when link clicked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to setup something using jQuery which will allow me to select a color from a list of links and have it highlight all divs that have this color as a class.  This is what I have so far...

```
<ul class="mybuttons">
    <li><a href="#" class="link red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link blue">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="test red blue">Red - Blue</div>
<div class="test blue">Blue</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test blue yellow">Blue - Yellow</div>
<div class="test orange">Orange</div>
<div class="test red">Red</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test green blue">Green - Blue</div>
<div class="test orange">Orange</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test green">Green</div>
<div class="test blue">Blue</div>
```

-

```
$( ".link.blue" ).click(function() {
 $(".test.blue").toggleClass("main");
 $(".link.blue").toggleClass("active");
});

$( ".link.red" ).click(function() {
$(".test.red").toggleClass("main");
$(".link.red").toggleClass("active");
});

$( ".link.yellow" ).click(function() {
$(".test.yellow").toggleClass("main");
$(".link.yellow").toggleClass("active");
});

$( ".link.orange" ).click(function() {
$(".test.orange").toggleClass("main");
$(".link.orange").toggleClass("active");
});

$( ".link.green" ).click(function() {
$(".test.green").toggleClass("main");
$(".link.green").toggleClass("active");
});
```

-

```
.test{height:30px;width:250px;background:lightgrey;margin-bottom:10px;border:black 1px solid;text-align:center}

.link{opacity:.5;}
.main{background:blue;color:white;}
.active{opacity:1;}

.link.red{background:red;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.green{background:green;green:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.yellow{background:yellow;color:black;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.blue{background:blue;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.orange{background:orange;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/box7ddu/q0f7w8zj/

It almost works, but if you highlight all of the colours then not all of the divs are highlighted,  also, i'm pretty sure the way I am doing it is not the most efficient.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would store the colours in `data-*` attributes, and use that to decide which of your `.test` elements will be active:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mybuttons">
    <li><a href="#" data-col="red" class="link red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="green" class="link green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="yellow" class="link yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="blue" class="link blue">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="orange" class="link orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$links = $('.link');
$links.click(function(e) {
    //Get our variables, simply $(this) and the colour
    var $this = $(this),
        color = $this.data('col');

    //Toggle the active class on this link
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    //Remove .main on all .test's
    $(".test").removeClass("main");

    //Map the active link's data-col with a dot attributes to an array
    //Join it up to make a selector
    var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
        return "."+$(this).data('col');
    }).get().join();

    //Add the class back on to matches
    $(selector).addClass('main');

    //Finally, prevent the default action
    //Lest you jump to the top of the page
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/q0f7w8zj/3/)

Comment: Thanks George, using the data attributes makes more sense now i've read up on it.

Comment: @fightstarr20 Glad to have helped you :)